# Mysql updating row on value change

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like following.(All are VARCHAR(255) except id and count which are INT)

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| id | code | descr | ccode | cdescr | count | display |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to make display to have following format (code)-(ccode)-(count)
What I mean is display value should be consisting of values from same row
And I want to update this display whenever a change occurs in this row, I heard about triggers (although I don't have much knowledge about them), but also read something that you can't update a table you put trigger on. Is this true? If it is, how I'm going to handle my situation?

Comment: The `display` field should not be stored in the database, since it is derived from other columns in the same fashion. Try `CONCAT()` when `SELECT`ing.

Comment: But I really need a column for this since I can't change the how the program works. I checked and definitely need to use concat function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making the Display column a `Generated Column`. Then the column will be part of the table, but only its value will only be generated when you read it.

> VIRTUAL: Column values are not stored, but are evaluated when rows are read,
>   immediately after any BEFORE triggers. A virtual column takes no
>   storage.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have the display column removed. (It has no own data, just a copy of other columns' data.)

Create a view instead:

```
create view viewname as
select id, code, descr, ccode, cdescr, count,
       concat('(', code, ')-(', ccode ')-(', cast(count as varchar(11)), ')') as display
from tablename
```

Will always return up-to date values in the display column!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about views. But I really need a column for this I can't change part of the program that uses database columns for this.

Comment: You have a view column here. Why do you need to save same data twice? Never mind, the other answer's generated column will do fine. (Almost like a view column added to a base table.)